# Phone gap device ready not fired after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sencha-touch

Am trying to build a Hellow World phone gap app using phonegap 3.1.

I did the following to generate my app

1. phonegap create WinREOCRM --id "com.winreocrm" --name "WinREOCRM"
2. phonegap local build android
3. phonegap local run android

Then i went to to my chrome open assets/www folder i can see the loading and finally device ready screen. Then i added some plugins network plugin, camera plugin, file upload plugin. Then i again visited assets/www folder using my chrome browser. Its only show the device is connecting screen, never get device connected screen. I got these messages in my console

```
device ready has not fired after 5 seconds  phonegap.js:1095
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
```

Here is my device ready function in index.js

```
 initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
 app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
```

I tried this so many times, i don't know how to solve this issue. I think the problem arise when i add plugin. Please help me to find the the solutions. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have this problem too. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I had this problem only when running in browser, in device it was working. To run it in browser i have just commented "plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information/www/network.js" file in assets/www/cordova_plugin.js file. I dont know it will work in your case

Comment: This is a known issue and as of time of writing, it hasn't been fixed, see the bug filed here [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5075]

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening your cordova.js/phonegap.js maybe you just use other platform like mine
I mistakenly use ios platform on an android project.

```
// Platform: ios
// 2.9.1
/*
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I confirmed that I am using the wrong platform.